# What is the significance of the Vertical integral of northward kinetic energy flux?

Tags: atmosphere

This is a field in the [ERA-Interim](http://data-portal.ecmwf.int/data/d/interim_daily/) dataset. What is its significance, and what is it important for?

Comment: Will you now open up a thread for each and every single one of the parameters in the dataset? Why are you specifically interested in this one?

Comment: Yes, more detail on the reason/context for the question would be useful.

Comment: @InquilineKea If I may, you ask a lot of (interesting) questions but don't seem very eager to follow on them, in particular to give feedbacks to comments. Doing so would help people considerably in giving you answers (especially considering the brevity of most of your questions).